# Add File Explorer Tab to DDMS?

Tags: android

I pressed some key and lost it. I've looked at every single eclipse menu and CANNOT see how to add this tab back. For God's sake can someone help?? This is so frustrating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Window Menu-->Show View---> File Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Restore perspective can also be done. Go to DDMS perspective and select
Window Menu->Reset Perspective

Comment: Thank you - I've been searching for these missing tabs for days. Where the hell does Eclipse hide them?!